# Are there any intersections between the biochemical pathways of uracil biosynthesis (or metabolism) and methionine degradation in eukaryotes?

Tags: biochemistry, metabolism

Is there any way in which uracil biosynthesis or metabolism could help cell in degradation of toxic levels of methionine?

Comment: Uracil degradation doesnt produce aspartate, but beta alanin

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think there are any intersections, and I can't see how uracil metabolism would have any influence upon methionine degradation.

Methionine degradation is shown in Figure 1 below. The end product is succinyl CoA which is fed into the TCA cycle. The only obvious by-product is cysteine which doesn't have any connection with uracil biosynthesis.

Uracil biosynthesis (as UMP) is shown in Figure 2: it is built from CO<sub>2</sub> and NH<sub>3</sub>. Uracil degradation produces CO<sub>2</sub> NH<sub>3</sub> and aspartate.

There are certainly no shared intermediates in these pathways, and I can't come up with any convincing indirect connections either.

**Figure 1. Methionine degradation**
[image]

**Figure 2. Uracil biosynthesis**

[image]

Comment: Theoretically, produced CO2 would buffer (minor) acidity from sulfate but that's both minor.